# Reserve space for flexbox items with variable width to prevent dynamic transferring to a new line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container and several items within. Its `flex-wrap` property is set to `wrap`.

Width of the items dynamically increases (via `animation` property) and at a given point some of them are moved to a new line. I'd like to prevent this behavior, reserving for the items as much space as they will occupy at the end.

I see two ways to achieve this. The first is setting initial margins and decrease them as the items width increases. The second is placing the items in wrappers with fixed width equal to their maximal width.

Is there a better way based on some flexbox properties? I can't apply `min-width` to the items as it breaks their layout.

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious answer be using the grid? Or is flexbox a musthave

Comment: @Blye I'd like to keep moving the items on a new line depending on container width. I just don't want it to be dynamic (when the items scale to its final width). Should I use a grid with `auto-fill`/`auto-fit` for that?